# ResponsiveSlides fixed height, not responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using ResponsiveSlides for a project of mine.
The problem is on big screens , the height of the slide is gigantic and I can't seem to adjust it , because if I do, either the image gets cut or the height of the image shrinks with bad ration.
I've tried max-height on the img , but it doesn't solve anything. I'm looking for something like the background-size: cover; would achieve.

I can't upload it to jsfiddle because it just doesn't work, ResponsiveSlides doesn't have a CDN.

What should I do?

Here are the screenshots:

Fullscreen : https://www.dropbox.com/s/dpnjxr9rltspxre/Screenshot%202015-04-11%2016.03.49.png?dl=0

I want it to look like this (which is half the size) :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7a8hmmp5txzoc7k/Screenshot%202015-04-11%2016.04.26.png?dl=0

Also having problems with making my div inside the slider, responsive, but that's for another time.

CSS:

```
.rslides 
position relative
list-style none
overflow hidden
width 100%
padding 0
margin 0


li 
    -webkit-backface-visibility hidden
    position absolute
    display none
    width 100%
    left 0
    top 0

    &::first-child 
        position relative
        display block
        float left
img
    display block
    height auto
    float left
    width 100%
    border 0






.caption
    position absolute
    display block
    text-align center
    width 20%
    margin 15% auto 0 auto
    left 0
    right 0
    padding 40px 80px
    background-color rgba(0,0,0,0.3)

    p
        font-size 18px
        margin-bottom 60px
        font-weight 400
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="rslides">
    <li>
        <img src="http://hdwallpaperd.com/wp-content/uploads/city_of_love-wallpaper-5120x3200.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
            <h2>Bem Vindo à FGSM</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id quam tempora ex provident ab laboriosam consequuntur, alias.</p>
            <a href="" class="btn-cta">Sobre Nós</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://hdwallpaperd.com/wp-content/uploads/city_of_love-wallpaper-5120x3200.jpg" alt="">

        <div class="caption">
            <h2>Bem Vindo à FGSM</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id quam tempora ex provident ab laboriosam consequuntur, alias.</p>
            <a href="" class="btn-cta">Sobre Nós</a>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://hdwallpaperd.com/wp-content/uploads/city_of_love-wallpaper-5120x3200.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
            <h2>Bem Vindo à FGSM</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id quam tempora ex provident ab laboriosam consequuntur, alias.</p>
            <a href="" class="btn-cta">Sobre Nós</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried `img{max-width:100%;}` ?

Comment: Yes, didn't work. The only solution was to switch slider.

Comment: No, simply switched the slider... still not the way I wanted. Thanks for worrying

Comment: Any option to share the website ?